# How to enrich a result source with a managed property?

Tags: search, refiner, result-source

in SPO we have a rudimentary people directory based on the ootb Local People Results result source. I have an additional metadata column in a SharePoint list which I would like to use as refinement values.

So I have already mapped the crawled propertiy to a managed properties (RefinableString111). Unfortunately, they do not surface any values when setting them up in the refiner webpart:

[image]

I guess that's because in the search results webpart the result source is set to "Local People Results":

[image]

And since the values for the managed property come from list data that is contained in the "Local SharePoint Results" it is used here. So I'm puzzled as to how I can include my RefinableString111 as a refiner acting upon the result source "Local People Results".

Is it possible to sort of "enrich" the existing result source with the managed property or create a new result source combining the two? Or is there possibly a totally different way of approaching this topic?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to enrich PersonA with PropertyA.
PersonA is a user profile in user profile service.
PropertyA is a column on a list.

Content Enrichment Service is not available in SPO. There is a user voice suggestion open: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/9581616-enable-the-content-enrichment-web-service-callout

SharePoint Search cannot match PropertyA with PersonA on people search directly. There is no connection between the user profile and the property.

I suggest on adding a new user profile property. This way you can add the property directly to the user profile. Then you would map RefinableString with this new property on the user profile.

The other way could be the following (I didn't test this scenario):

- Create a new content type and add it to a list
- Add a people column and your PropertyA column to this content type
- Add at least one item to the list with this content type
- Index this list
- Now you should be able to filter by this new content type and display PersonA with PropertyA on the search results page. I'm not sure on how to expand the people column values to display on the search result page.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the Property on the User Profile itself. Then once the Properties are crawled you can map the crawled property to a managed property in the PeopleIdx context. The property will now be available in the People Result Source.